# initWithAppID command crashed

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox

I am new with Android programming and especially with PayPal. I got an application that was tasked to troubleshoot - despite being new to Android, is crashing at this line:

`initWithAppID(this.getBaseContext(), appID, PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);`

Firstly, `PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX` always returns a 0 which I am not sure if its suppose to. Secondly, why is it always crashing there? I have searched online for the reason, people says its because it did not fully initialized thats why its failing. Now I would like to know what I need to do if I cant initialize this library?

I am using Eclipse IDE, testing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab Android 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this will help but this is how I fixed it while testing with PayPal.ENV_NONE (from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/PayPalPlugin/src/com/phonegap/plugin/mpl.java)

```
PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
if (pp == null) {
    try {
        pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(getApplicationContext(), "", PayPal.ENV_NONE);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    pp.setShippingEnabled(false);
}
```

Then when creating the button:

```
PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
CheckoutButton cb = pp.getCheckoutButton(
        getBaseContext(), 
        PayPal.BUTTON_194x37, 
        CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();
    // set subtotal etc ...
    Intent i = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment,getApplicationContext());
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
});
```

Hope that helps somehow

Comment: Thanks, I will see how and where do I implement these statement in the code and see if it works. Or can I just use `PayPal.initWithAppID(getApplicationContext(), "", PayPal.ENV_NONE);` instead?

Comment: The top code should initialize it for ENV_NONE. That is the easiest case to get working. When that works go back to trying to get ENV_SANDBOX working. What does the log say when it crashes?

Comment: something about a null pointer, hard to pinpoint the problem that way. but when i do a debug while running, it crashed at that line...

Answer (score 0):

Can you specifiy more information about this method? Is it a paypal library method? 
I think the PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX is some environment variable you have to set. The name suggests that this settings is used for testing purposes or for developing (not actually doing any payments).
I think you might find out more about this method in the library documentation.
A second question is, have you used the right appId? And is the base context the right context to use? Maybe you have to use the getApplicationContext, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext%28%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29).

Comment: the capital casing shows ENV_SANDBOX is a constant of the PayPal class, which shouldn't be and even can't be set. So it to return 0 everytime is by design as apparently that is its constant value. Obviously there will be more ENV_* constants in the PayPal class that can be passed to the initWithAppID.

Comment: True. But I don't know the PayPal library. There may be more then 1 library available with exactly the same API. One working for products and one for development with the PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX telling which one you use. Again, i don't now the real meaning of this constant, but i suppose PayPal has documentation of it.

Comment: The same library is used for all ENV_* types. 
When you pass ENV_SANDBOX PayPal will perform all operations on their Sandbox server (for testing). 
You can pass ENV_LIVE when your app is ready to go live. 
You can also pass ENV_NONE in which case the library will perform all operations internally (simulating network messages). Their is one App ID for Sandbox (APP-80W284485P51943T). You are meant to initialize it once then retrieve it via PayPal.getInstance(). I'm having the same problem, just thought I'd add what little extra I know

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. But unfortunately, I was thrown this project and was asked to test and troubleshoot any errors occurred. Thus giving me this problem. But I believe the ENV_SANDBOX is a variable comes from the PayPal library. I read up the Documentations for the Android PayPal and saw it there along with 2 other variables.